# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE - semicolon

Tags: php, mysql

My IDE is expecting a semicolon but I'm not sure where!
It is this line it is highlighting:

```
,'$other_writ'  WHERE id="$_SESSION[user_id]")
```

This is the code above:

```
 if (!empty($_POST['doLanguage']) && $_POST['doLanguage'] == 'Submit') 
{ 
  session_start();
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
  $id = "$_SESSION[user_id]";

  if(empty($err)) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["other"]); $i++);
{
$native = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['native'][$i]);
$other = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['other'][$i]);
$other_list = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['other_list'][$i]);
$other_read = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['other_read'][$i]);
$other_spokint = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['other_spokint'][$i]);
$other_spokprod = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['other_spokprod'][$i]);
$other_writ = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['other_writ'][$i]);
$sql_insert = "INSERT into `language`
(`native`,`other`,`other_list`,`other_read`, `other_spokint`
,`other_spokprod`,`other_writ`  )
VALUES
('$native','$other','$other_list','$other_read','$other_spokint','$other_spokprod'
,'$other_writ'  WHERE id="$_SESSION[user_id]")";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());     
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you have an additional semi-colon on the line where you define your for loop: `for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["other"]); $i++);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open a string here:

```
"INSERT into `language` ...
```

and it's being closed here:

```
... WHERE id="
```

PHP expects a semicolon after this. You could fix it by replacing the double quotes with single quotes (which are the SQL standard), **but**: *why are you using a `WHERE` clause with `INSERT` anyway*? You don't need that.

Just finish your string like this:

```
... ,'$other_writ')";
```

Comment: I am using a user login system so this page links from their 'my account' page and therefore need the session to be right for this user.

Comment: So you should check the user with PHP before running the query. Your `WHERE` does absolutely nothing (and may even break the query).

Comment: Sorry how is the best way to do this? I'm a total newbie!

Comment: Something like this (on the top of your PHP): `if(empty($_SESSION[user_id])) { // user not logged in; redirect to somewhere else }`

Answer (score 1):

```
,'$other_writ'  WHERE id=" . $_SESSION[user_id] . ")
```

So you missed a concatenation operator `.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
,'$other_writ'  WHERE id="$_SESSION[user_id]")";
```

to

```
,'$other_writ'  WHERE id=" . $_SESSION[user_id] . ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things;

- $_SESSION[user_id] is quoted with `"` in the middle of a string that's in its entirety quoted with `"`. The broken `WHERE` part, being a bit misplaced in an `INSERT` anyway, can be removed entirely.
- Your for loop doesn't do much;

  `for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["other"]); $i++);`

The semicolon at the end makes it an empty loop. Remove it and things should work better.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error

```
" WHERE id="$_SESSION[user_id]")";
```

you should use this way

```
" WHERE id=."$_SESSION[user_id].")";
```

also you have opened two curly parentheses but closed one.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need a concatenation operator here:

```
WHERE id=" . $_SESSION[user_id] . ")";
```

Or like this:

```
WHERE id={$_SESSION[user_id]} )";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $sql_insert string should look like this. Pay attention right before the WHERE.

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT into `language`
(`native`,`other`,`other_list`,`other_read`, `other_spokint`
,`other_spokprod`,`other_writ`  )
VALUES
('$native','$other','$other_list','$other_read','$other_spokint','$other_spokprod','$other_writ')  WHERE id = '{$_SESSION[user_id]}'";
```